# Why would people buy bitcoin these days if its too expensive?

Tags: exchange-rate, price-volatility, price-discovery

I'm curious on why would bitcoin rise in the near future since its not affordable anymore. It's actually but for wealthy people only. How could it even reach mass adoption because of its extreme price?

It seems reasonable that people will switch to alt-coins because of their lower prices hence that would cause bitcoin to loose its value over time since people will start to sell it..

How can people/experts make claims that we could see bitcoin over 100k etc. It's total nonsense or am I missing something?

Comment: When Bitcoin price was less than 1$ and reached 20,000$ Does this fact make any sense?

Comment: Why would anyone want a ten dollar bill if it costs a thousand pennies?  Isn't a thousand a really big number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably missing is the fact that you can buy partial bitcoins, you don't have to purchase a whole bitcoin at once. You could buy a small bit of bitcoin for $20 if you wanted, it can be an affordable investment for anyone.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely missed but again, you know people mindset who wants a quarter, half? We all want at least a whole number....

Comment: @eugene_sunic: Evidently, lots of people don't feel that way.  You can look at any Bitcoin exchange and see lots of trades for much less than 1 BTC.  So I think your assumptions are simply mistaken.

Comment: Well they obviously are. Will look at the exchange more carefully to examine the situation... Tnx guys for the reply

Comment: @eugene_sunic please remember to accept my answer if it satisfied your question :)